# Issues with encoding when loading csv-file in RShiny

Tags: r, encoding, shiny

I have a shinyapp deployed on a local linux-server, and I got problems when importing a csv-file.

That is to say that I want to import this file and render it as table,

[image]

but instead it only gives me this:

[image]

So, basically the import stopped when an unknown letter appeared: **µ**.

The log-file shows me the following warning:

```
  ungÃ¼ltige Eingabe gefunden in der Eingabeverbindung '/tmp/RtmpxgsBZW/7412c490cbdaa77392dc5a54/0.csv'
Warnung in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, 
  unvollstÃ¤dige letzte Zeile von readTableHeader in '/tmp/RtmpxgsBZW/7412c490cbdaa77392dc5a54/0.csv' gefunden
```

I only encounter this problem on the shiny server, but I never had this when working locally within RStudio.

I assume it has something to do with the default encoding of the server, but I am not quite sure of how to acess all this details.

Here is the crucial snipped of my code which leads to the explained problem:

`read.delim(input$file$datapath,header=TRUE,sep=";",dec=".",fileEncoding="UTF-8")`

Any help much appreciated, and please let me know if I should get additional information about anything.

Comment: Although I would prefer using read.csv over read.delim there is nothing wrong with your code. There is an empty row at the bottom of your file. You have to delete that line and then there should be no issue with importing

Comment: Ok, really stupid mistake - it was the wrong encoding ("latin1"). But thanks for the confirmation - it helped me to check again where the problem could lie...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: i used the wrong encoding, so my code was correct apart from that. So for everyone who might at some point stumble over this post. Just make sure that you are really using the correct encoding before spending too many hours trying to find your bug in the code.